Question on hold for a different reason to the reason I gave
This is in relation to How does this Anamorphic illusion work?
I noticed there were several votes to close for an "unclear question" and when I voted, I voted to migrate to PhysicsSE.  However when I submitted my close vote, it attached my name to "unclear question" and not that it is a better fit within PhysicsSE (see the comment which was posted at exactly the moment I submitted my close-vote).  This tipped the balance of votes.  How can that happen?
Who voted for what is not shown whilst voting is underway, however the number of votes for what is shown.  Below is an example

When voting is closed and been deemmed a majority, the names of those who voted for that majority vote is shown with the close reason. Below is what is on the Anamorphic Illusion question

In response to @StevenJeuris, I am not against my name being attributed to a majority close reason when I voted for it, but I didn't vote to close for "unclear question". I voted for migration.

I am not sure I understand what you are asking. I believe it just picks the close reason the majority voted for.

This is the thing. There were (if memory serves me correctly) 4 votes for "unclear question", 1 vote for either "too broad" or "opinion-based" - I believe it was the former - and now my vote for migration tips it to 5 votes for "unclear question" when that is not my vote. My name is attached to "unclear question" when I voted for migration through "off-topic (other)"

When a question is closed, it does not show who voted for what. It simply shows one close reason (the majority, or the one decided by a moderator) attributed to all people that voted to close. The specific votes are not listed.
In case you would argue this should be done differently, you can do so on the main Meta site:
Please anonymize rather than incorrectly attribute close reasons to users

I have added a comment to the post you suggested, although it was closed as an exact duplicate of another request when actually it is different!!!  Seeing as this request was made 3 years ago, it doesn't seem that the "stackexchange management" are in any hurry to change things when the "so-called" duplicate has an accepted alternative.

I have now reposted at stackexchange meta on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298551/please-keep-close-hold-voting-open-until-the-minimum-is-reached-on-the-relevant
